# How would I create expanding content like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a portfolio website and I've had an idea for how I should display my work but I'm struggling to figure out how to implement it the way I want.

The idea is to have a page full of images, in a grid like pattern, you would then click on a link on the image and a description of the project would slide out beside it, moving the other images over (and on to new lines if line is full). The site is also going to be responsive, so the number of images on each line will change based on device.

**This JSFiddle shows what I have at the moment and what I want it to look like when used: http://jsfiddle.net/k7NFu/2/**

This was what i had in mind for the HTML mark-up, but obviously make any changes if necessary (see fiddle for more info):

```
<li>
    <div class="overlay"> <a href="#" class="view_project">View Project</a>
        <img src="https://placeit.net/uploads/stage/stage_image/427/small_IMG_3839_base_2.jpg" alt="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <p>Quisque augue lectus, interdum id lectus nec, pulvinar mollis sapien. Phasellus sed consectetur sapien. Integer gravida mauris vitae elit vestibulum, tincidunt volutpat leo vulputate. Vivamus at nibh massa.</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

I've experimented with `.slideToggle()` in the past but that only allows vertical expanding (I think), so any ideas you guys have would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a basic example I made [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vqdsx/). Shows what you need to do, this is still using all percentages. (Click the images)

Comment: @Ruddy Ok, yeah that's basically what I want, but sorry I forgot to mention it's going to have media queries that change how many images are displayed on each row on different devices, so just setting a new width with .css() might not be exactly what I need. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can slide left/rigth using the following

```
 $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
 $(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

but you will need jquery ui aswell

**EDIT**:

Full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xcy8Y/

**HTML**

```
 <div id=trigger>Open/Close</div><div class=hidden>Hidden info box</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 //... Previous code
 $("#trigger").click(function(){
      $(".hidden").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
 });
 // Rest of code ...
```

**CSS**

```
 .hidden{
      display: none
 }
 div{
      float: left;
 }
```

Ofcourse you could put whatever you whant in the div tags, in your case probably the pictures.

Comment: OK cheers, I will give it a go using that after work. would you be able to make a basic quick example for me for reference please?

Answer (score 0):

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7NFu/3/)

**jQuery :**

```
$('.description').css({'display':'none'});
$('.opened').on('click','.overlay',function(){
    $(this).next('.description').slideToggle();
});
```